# TransactionScopeOption - Required or RequiresNew

Tags: .net, transactions, constructor, transactionscope

I'm currently having a confusion concerning the constructor of the TransactionScope object.

Say that users of my website can order products. On submitting their request, I carry out a verification of the current quantity left and if it is still greater than zero, I carry out the request. Then, at the end I decrement the current quantity left.

The whole process is within a transaction, using .NET transactionScope.

After reading several articles on .NET transactionScope object, I'm now a bit confused about the value of the TransactionScopeOption to use for the constructor of the transactionScope.

Which one of the following is more appropriate for the case described above:

```
public void ProcessRequest()  
 {  
     TransactionOptions transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions();  
     transactionOptions.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable;  
     using (TransactionScope currentScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, transactionOptions)) {  
      // DB Query to verify if quantity is still greater than zero  
      // DB Query to request and decrement quantity 
      currentScope.Complete();
     }  
 }
```

**OR**

```
public void ProcessRequest()  
 {  
     TransactionOptions transactionOptions = new TransactionOptions();  
     transactionOptions.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable;  
     using (TransactionScope currentScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, transactionOptions)) {  
      // DB Query to verify if quantity is still greater than zero  
      // DB Query to request and decrement quantity 
      currentScope.Complete();
     }  
 }
```

Note that the above is just an over simplification of my actual problem. I'm only interested in knowing the right value of the TransactionScopeOption (**RequiresNew** or **Required**) for such a case.

Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It depends what you want to happen if another method calls `ProcessRequest` **inside another  transaction**:

```
public void SomeOtherMethod() {
    using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope()) {
        // Another DB action
        ProcessRequest();
        // Yet another DB action
    }
}
```

If you want `ProcessRequest` to use the transaction created by `SomeOtherMethod`, use `TransactionScope.Required`. This is the default (and it still creates a transaction when you call it without having created another transaction scope up the call stack).

If you want it to force this method to always use its own (new) transaction, use `TransactionScope,RequiresNew`.

Comment: In my case, the method ProcessRequest itself will never participate inside another transaction.

I'm only looking to ensure that after a request executes:

"DB Query to verify if quantity is still greater than zero"

by the time it executes:

"DB Query to request and decrement quantity"

the quantity has not yet reached zero because of another request, executing the same method ProcessRequest.

So, I guess the default: TransactionScope.Required is the correct value for me.

Comment: Definitely - otherwise, you'd be (unintentionally) implying that there was something special about ProcessRequest that required it to use its own transaction.

Answer (score 14):

I understand your method won't be called in another transaction. But in case it will, here is how you choose `TransactionScopeOption`.

If the content written to database by ProcessRequest cannot be overturned by any caller, use `RequiresNew`, which starts a new transaction **parallel** to the one created by the caller(if any), and the new transaction is not managed by the caller by any means. **It's best to think transaction cannot be nested, either use existing transaction or create a new one.** Transaction is not nested!

If the content written to database by ProcessRequest can be overturned, use `Required`. However, this option is not transparent; caller to ProcessRequest must be aware that ProcessRequest may roll back because if callee rolls back the ambient transaction, caller cannot perform any sql operation, otherwise exception "The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction." will be thrown. It's probably best to always check `System.Transactions.Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation.Status` before running any query as you won't know if any callee furtively created a transaction and rolled it back.

You may find the following table useful.
[image]