# Nested TransactionScope errors

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions

This problem was posted several times but it never got a good answer.

Basically, when using nested TransactionScopes, if an exception is thrown, the ambient transaction is aborted and no DB operation or new transaction is allowed.

Note that it's mandatory (for me) to use TransactionScopeOption.Required on inner transactions, not TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew because I need the whole transaction to be controlled by the top most transaction.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35952497/628661 for some details.

Is there a solution for this?

EDIT: Db is SQL Server

```
        using (var transactionScope1 = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
        {
            using (var transactionScope2 = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
            {
                try 
                {
                    // ...
                    throw new();  // simulate exception
                    transactionScope2.Complete();
                }
                catch { }
            }

            // error: The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction
            var data = await myDbContext.MyTable.FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            // error: The transaction has aborted
            using (var transactionScope3 = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
            {
                // ...
                transactionScope3.Complete();
            }
        }
```

Comment: The answer is in the link you posted! so when the inner transaction is rolled back then there is no meaning in using the outer transaction.

Comment: The link just shows how it works out of the box. There is meaning for me, that's why I asked here. The question is if it is possible or if there is a workaround

Comment: The answer is dependent on your database, which you didn't specify.  For SQL Server, at least, a rollback in a inner transaction will roll back the outer transaction, but there is a separate savepoint mechanism that you can possibly use instead.

Comment: @David Db is SQL Server. I updated my post. Can you give me more details?

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server you can control the fate of the transaction in the outer scope, but any inner scope can doom the transaction.  If any inner scope rolls back, the outer transaction cannot be committed.

See, eg [A SQL Server DBA myth a day: (26/30) nested transactions are real](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/)

You might be able to use [savepoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/save-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to get the behavior you desire.